# Transforming db data to json in web2py for visualization with flot.js

Tags: python, json, web2py

I'm having problem to get a valid json string for flot.js visualisation from db data in web2py.

This is my controller action:

```
def getdata():
    return dict(data=db().select(db.realtimedata.id, db.realtimedata.FlowRate, limitby=(0, 3), orderby=~db.realtimedata.id))
```

Generic json view returns this json string for getdata action:

```
{"data": [{"id": 1, "FlowRate": 373}, {"id": 2, "FlowRate": 379}, {"id": 3, "FlowRate": 376}]}
```

How can i get this json string?

```
[[1,373],[2,379],[3,376]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

def getdata():
    rows = db().select(db.realtimedata.id, db.realtimedata.FlowRate,
                       limitby=(0, 3), orderby=~db.realtimedata.id)
    return json.dumps([[r.id, r.FlowRate] for r in rows])
```

Note, the above returns a string directly, so no view will be called.

Comment: how about using rows.as_json() ?

Comment: No, the `as_json` method doesn't generate the format required by the OP.